# How do I use a 'q' to call an API and get a response in Django views?

Tags: python, django, python-requests, response

I'm trying to query this api and get a response but I'm obviously not doing it correctly as i know its not as simple as this.

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):
    response = request.GET["https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/?q=8+bd+du+port"}
    return render(request, "home.html", {'response': response})
```

I would like to be able to give an address to the API ie: "8 Boulevard du Port 80000 Amiens" and
get the associated information about it. ie: gps coordinates

this is the api: https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/api

I can't seem to find information on how to make this kind of request and handle the response using views in django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.GET` is a dictionary-like object containing all given HTTP GET parameters also called Query parameters or Query string.

`requests` is a simple HTTP library for Python that allows you to send HTTP/1.1 requests.

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

import requests
from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):
    url = "https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/?q={}"
    address = "8 Boulevard du Port 80000 Amiens"
    response = requests.get(url.format(quote_plus(address)))
    # response.json()  # this will give you JSON response
    return render(request, "home.html", {"response": response})
```

Comment: Thank you Vishal Singh. That took away my errors. The response I get is: <Response [200]> Does this mean I need to parse out the data?

Comment: @JohnMullen yes you need to use `response.json()` to get the JSON output. I've updated this in answer.

Comment: THANK YOU Vishal Singh!! I returned the json() method like so:
`data = response.json()` and `return render(request, "home.html", {"data": data})` and got a JSON output. Is this the best approach for using a portion of the data ie: the gps coordinates?